# Searching and using databases

Tags: r

`df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')`

`df8 <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers-Scraping/master/countries.csv')`

In the 1st dataset, there are countries divided into continents.

In the second data set, there is country and population information.

How can I combine population information in data set 2 according to the continental information in data set 1.

thank you. The problem is that in the 1st dataset, countries are written on a continental basis. Countries and their populations in the second dataset. Do I need the population information of the continents? eg europe = 400 million, asia = 2.4 billion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dplyr package all you have to do is join by a common variable, in this case country name. Since in one data frame the name is called `countryName` and in the other one `country_name`, we just have to specify that they in fact belong to the same variable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
    left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
    mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>% 
    group_by(countryName) %>%
    slice_tail(1) %>% 
    group_by(region) %>% 
    summarize(population = sum(population, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  region   population
* <chr>         <dbl>
1 Africa   1304908713
2 Americas 1019607512
3 Asia     4592311527
4 Europe    738083720
5 Oceania    40731992
```

Comment: thank you. The problem is that in the 1st dataset, countries are written on a continental basis. Countries and their populations in the second dataset. Do I need the population information of the continents? eg europe = 400 million, asia = 2.4 billion

Comment: Ah I'll see. Let me fix my answer.

Comment: I've added a correction to my answer, let me know if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: yeah but why doesn't it work for me ... gives this error.
Error in df%>% left_join (df8, by = c (countryName = "country_name"))%>%:
  Function "%>%" not found

Comment: You need to install the dplyr package ... install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: Error in str_remove_all (population, ","):
  The function "str_remove_all" could not be found.

gave this error

Comment: Ah I apologize. I used the stringr package as well because the populations were poorly formatted. Basically, just use install.packages("stringr") too. Those are all the packages you need, I promise! ... Or if you want, you can replace the str_remove_all function for the gsub(",", "", population) function.